# Program launches for standard account but not administrator account

Tags: windows-7

Running windows 7 64-bit. lately having a very strange problem. one of the installed programs launches for the standard account but not administrator account. can anyone suggest any reason?

Comment: What's the program, how are you trying to start it and what happens?  Do you get any messages?

Comment: Its Adobe Digital Editions 2.0. I am trying to run it as administrator  from the administrator account. UAC prompt opens. then, the program does not get launched. i do not receive any other messages. i am the administrator of the system. when i launch it from the standard user account it does get launched.

Answer (score 0):

There are software packages that install to just the currently logged in user's account, all user accounts, or even still, the software prompts you for your preference.  I took the liberty of downloading a copy of Adobe Digital Editions 2.0 (http://www.adobe.com/products/digital-editions/download.html) and the installer made no mention to either of the three scenarios listed above.

My advice would be to try installing the package logged in as administrator.

Comment: thanx for the advice. i install all the programs on my system logged in as administrator. and did the same for ADE from the first instance. i have tried uninstalling and reinstalling a number of times but of no use.

Comment: i would like to add, its been a few months that i used ADE. before that everything was working fine. when i saw this problem, i even redownload the installer and did the reinstallation. a little while ago i did mess up with the permissions on the system. when i checked the permissions for the program, its granted for administrator, system, my account. can that be a issue? which all permissions need to be granted for a program like this?